# Yolov5 with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch, object-detection, yolov5

I trained a model using the Yolov5 Google Colab notebook with custom data and classes.
I used the detect.py script to do object detection on a video with no issues.

I downloaded the .pt file and loaded it into a script I stored on my machine based on Yolov5's Github example for Screenshot Inference and it worked great when I used it on an image on my PC: https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/36

Now that I know that the PyTorch file can be loaded without issues and that detection is working, I am trying to perform real-time detection by taking screenshots of my screen. I can record my screen by taking screenshots without issue but when I try to do so with the model, I get an error. Here is my code:

```py
import time
import torch
import cv2
import mss
import numpy

# Load model
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='last_210_epochs_Size1280.pt') 

with mss.mss() as sct:
    # Part of the screen to capture
    monitor = sct.monitors[2]

    while "Screen capturing":
        last_time = time.time()

        # Get raw pixels from the screen, save it to a Numpy array
        img = numpy.array(sct.grab(monitor))

        results = model(img)
        

        # Display the picture
        cv2.imshow('test', results)

        # Display the picture in grayscale
        # cv2.imshow('OpenCV/Numpy grayscale',
        #            cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY))

        print("fps: {}".format(1 / (time.time() - last_time)))

        # Press "q" to quit
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

This is the error that I get:

[image]

Not exactly sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `results` is not a numpy array, nor a valid image, so you can't `imshow` it.

Comment: @stateMachine I see, so there is nothing that can be done?

Comment: Well, I don't know what you are trying to do. `results` is probably a list of classes, probabilities and bounding box coordinates (pure speculation, since the code is not reproducible). It does not make sense to `cv2.imshow` that, since that data is not an image. You probably want to draw bounding boxes on your input image. In that case, iterate through the results container and extract the info. You can use `cv2.rectangle` to draw rectangles on the images using the bounding boxes coordinates.

Comment: @stateMachine You were right, even though 'results' is performing the detection correctly, it is not an image. instead, it is a <class 'models.common.Detections'> object so it's no wonder OpenCV is having a hard time showing it. Now, I just have to figure out how to maybe convert this object to an image for OpenCV

Comment: Check if the results object has a "bounding box coordinates" field. It should be, perhaps a tuple of four variables containing x, y , width and height of the box, or some data to further calculate those four dimensions, this is what you need in order to draw the rectangles via OpenCV. I highly doubt that the object has the final resulting image with the rectangles already drawn, but perhaps I'm wrong here.

Comment: @stateMachine What I see is something like so:
"Speed: 15.5ms pre-process, 1196.0ms inference, 2.0ms NMS per image at shape (1, 3, 384, 640)
image 1/1: 1080x1920 1 YH - 5H, 1 YH - 8H".
This is when it makes a detection.
Speed: 15.0ms pre-process, 1205.5ms inference, 1.0ms NMS per image at shape (1, 3, 384, 640)
image 1/1: 1080x1920 (no detections).
This is when it doesn't make a detection.
I don't see bounding box coordinates. Sorry for msging you privately, I did that by mistake

Answer (score 1):

I solved this error using:

```
cv2.imshow('frame', np.squeeze(result.render()))
```

Comment: GOATED reply <3